# Error while using Hive context in spark : object hive is not a member of package org.apache.spark.sql

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I am trying to construct a Hive Context ,which inherits from SQLContext.

```
val sqlContext = new org.apache.spark.sql.hive.HiveContext(sc)
```

I get the following error:

```
error: object hive is not a member of package org.apache.spark.sql
       val sqlContext = new org.apache.spark.sql.hive.HiveContext(sc)
```

I can clearly see from the autocompletion that hive doest not exist.
Any ideas on how to resolve this?  This is an example fromthe sparkSQL documentation available.

Thank you

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Because of hive's dependencies it is not compiled into the spark binary by default you have to build it yourself. Quote from the [website](http://spark.apache.org/docs/1.1.0/sql-programming-guide.html#hive-tables)

However, since Hive has a large number of dependencies, it is not included in the default Spark assembly. In order to use Hive you must first run `sbt/sbt -Phive assembly/assembly` (or use -Phive for maven).

Comment: What do you mean by sbt/sbt -Phive assembly/assembly? What should I replace assembly with?

Answer (score 20):

Using sbt:

You have to include spark-hive in your dependencies.

To do so add the following line in your .sbt file:

`libraryDependencies += "org.apache.spark" %% "spark-hive" % "1.5.0"`

Answer (score 3):

Here's an example maven dependency

```
<dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
        <artifactId>spark-hive_${scala.tools.version}</artifactId>
        <version>${spark.version}</version>
</dependency>
```

--- for those who need to know how to set the properties in POM, below is an example

```
<properties>
        <maven.compiler.source>1.7</maven.compiler.source>
        <maven.compiler.target>1.7</maven.compiler.target>
        <encoding>UTF-8</encoding>
        <scala.tools.version>2.10</scala.tools.version>
        <scala.version>2.10.4</scala.version>
        <spark.version>1.5.0</spark.version>
</properties>
```

Answer (score 0):

For Maven projects, after you add the HIVE dependency, just click the "Update Project" by right-clicking on your project -> Maven -> Update Project. This should solve the issue.