# SBT cannot build with spark-hive dependency

Tags: scala, sbt, apache-spark-sql

I am trying to compile a scala script to submit a job through spark-submit. I am using sbt from Windows command line to compile. Directory structure is as defined by sbt.

path = C:\users\{$username}

```
{$path}\test
         |-src
         |  |-main
         |  |  |-scala
         |  |  |-java
         |  |  |-resources
         |  |-test
         |     |-scala
         |     |-java
         |     |-resources
         |-target
         build.sbt
```

Here is my build file:
build.sbt

```
name := "TestQuery"
version := "1.0"
scalaVersion := "2.11.8"

libraryDependencies ++= {
   val sparkVer = "2.1.0"
   Seq("org.apache.spark" %% "spark-core" % sparkVer % "provided"   withSources(),
   "org.apache.spark" %% "spark-hive" % sparkVer % "provided" )
}
```

My TestQuery.scala file is under ./test/src/main/scala/TestQuery.scala

From Windows cmd, I switch directory to ./test and run sbt. When I run `compile` command, sbt gives the following error:

```
[error]./test/src/main/scala/TestQuery.scala:2:29: 
object hive is not a member of package org.apache.spark.sql
```

sbt uses maven2 repository and spark-hive exists under:
https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/apache/spark/spark-hive_2.11/1.2.0/

Also, this import command works in spark-shell. (spark-shell runs Spark 2.1.1. and scala 2.11.8).

Why can't it find it?

Comment: If I understand correctly, you run `sbt` not from the root of your project, but from a subfolder `test`. This is wrong. Try running `sbt` from the root of the project.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. C:\users\{$username}\test is the root directory for project (as I understand it).

Comment: will this help you ?  [error-while-using-hive-context-in-spark](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26637210/error-while-using-hive-context-in-spark-object-hive-is-not-a-member-of-package)